# rsync multiple IP's using bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to use rsync to synchronise remote files with local server. It works great but I want to do it on multiple remote servers to sync with on daily basis.

```
sshpass -p "xyz" rsync -avz lanein1@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:BrandStIN/ /home/lanein1/BrandStIN/
sshpass -p "xyz" rsync -avz lanein1@yy.yyy.yyy.yyy:MarySt/ /home/lanein1/MarySt/
sshpass -p "xyz" rsync -avz lanein1@aa.aaa.aaa.aaa:IWM/ /home/lanein1/IWM/
```

I have 10 IP numbers which I have to rsync  daily for checking , How I can do that by using BASH script. So that I can automate that task by using cron. I want BASH script only.

I am struck here.I have all the Ip addresses in a text file and dont know how to call the file on rsync with their passwords.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program name: rsyncall.sh
date
cat /path/to/IP.txt |  while read output
do........
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with two servers. To stress the system as little as possible, I use `nice` and `ionice`

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read ip; do 
    /usr/bin/nice -n 19 \
    /usr/bin/ionice -c 3 \
    /usr/bin/rsync --delete --delete-excluded --password-file=/home/aboettger/.rsync_pwd  -av /home/aboettger/Music rsync://$ip/media;
done < host_names
```

Adapted for you

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read ip; do 
    rsync --password-file=rsync_pwd_file -avz rsync://$ip/BrandStIN /home/lanein1/BrandStIN
    rsync --password-file=rsync_pwd_file -avz rsync://$ip/MarySt /home/lanein1/MarySt
    rsync --password-file=rsync_pwd_file -avz rsync://$ip/IWM /home/lanein1/IWM
done < host_names
```

---

Content of `host_names`

```
% cat host_names
192.168.2.40
192.168.2.41
```